# Can't negate spring default profile in YAML file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I can't negate profile in my YML configuration:

```
spring:
    autoconfigure:
        exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
    profiles:
        default: '!mock'
```

Above configuration comes from `application-mock.yml`, earlier I was using `properites` files where everything worked well, but now I migrate it to `yml` based configuration, and when starting my Spring Boot application (ofc with mock active profile) I get an error about missing bean as parameter constructor. How can I solve this issue?